# Weighted observations for linear model

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, caret

I have dataset with sale price of products in years 2015-2020. I would like use it to predict future sale prices. I would like to use sale year as a weight of observation (eg. for 2020-100%, for 2019-90%, for 2018-80% and so on). Whether it makes sense to do so? How to do it? I use R and caret package.

Thanks